# Javascript function in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

Can anyone pinpoint what the issue is here? Should be very simple and straightforward

http://jsfiddle.net/WSCBu/146/

```
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle('id1','id2');">Toggle Div</a>
<div id="id1" style="display:block;"><p>test 1</p></div>
<div id="id2" style="display:none;"><p>test 2</p></div>

function toggle(one, two) {      
   var i = document.getElementById(one);     
   var i2 = document.getElementById(two);
   if(i.style.display == 'block') {                
      i.style.display = 'none';             
      i2.style.display = 'block';
   }
   else {
      i.style.display = 'block';            
      i2.style.display = 'none';
   }              
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code here if you desire community assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this question is not very related to Salesforce or Visualforce. You should actually ask it in stackoverflow.

Then, to answer your question, your code is not seriously wrong, but jsfiddle wraps the javascript part of code inside the execution of Window.init() function. So your html code doesn't have the scope of your toggle() method. I have changed it into the jQuery style click function. And here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LanceShi/j3tepeLf/3/

Also, although this is not quite related to your issue, keep in mind you should use === instead of == in your javascript.

Comment: Thank you, Lance. This also wouldn't work in my visualforce so I thought it would be a related issue. I'll take note to ask in stackoverflow next time. Does visualforce also wrap the javascript in Window.init()?

Comment: @Andrew No, it doesn't. If the jsfiddle works for you. It should also work for you in your VF page. Otherwise, you can paste your VF page code here and we can take a look at it for you.

Comment: @Andrew feel free to ask for re-open this question if you have edited your question. But anyway, I will try to help.

Comment: Much appreciated, Lace. I'll just have to do individual research about Window.Init(). Thanks again for your help.